# Approach to write Test scenarios and Test Cases

Tags: manual-testing, test-design

My question is if -I write all test scenarios for specific module in one excel sheet with stating number of test cases can be written and another excel sheet for test cases (for specific module) would this approach work well for Agile methodology?

NOTE: we were not ready to use any tools.

Comment: Agile does not force to write test cases in particular format. You can write in general standard way.

Comment: as u know we are using agile methodology , we need better maintenance of test scenarios with test cases will it be possible?

Comment: you can use test case management tool. i.e http://www.gurock.com/testrail/  It will allow to maintain easy rather than excel.

Comment: @Helping Hands i don't think this will be my answer, but we are not in position to purchase or use tool to maintain the Test scenario.

Comment: You did not mentioned in question that you do not want to use any ready made tool. So I suggested. also you want to maintain things in smooth and for long term then only tool can help you and better than excel.

Comment: I am particularly curious about why not using a test case management tool- an open source option like Test Link?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Helping Hands correctly said- Agile doesn't dictates the way or the format in which you write or arrange test cases. But for your greater good, you should have separate excel sheets for different modules (considering the application isn't a huge one with lots of functionality).

It would be a lot easier to manage and execute test cases (manually), following this approach.

Answer (score 2):

The very idea of agile is that you have to find out *what works best for you*. If you follow a rule written by anyone external to the project without at least questioning it, then you're not agile.

In that spirit, I'd say that if a sheet becomes too big(read : you begin to feel it's huge when you work with it)n then it's time to split the sheet. And if you begin to split by module, then do it fully for staying consistent.

Answer (score 0):

Agile methodologie does not require any specific tool and, above all, does not provide limitations to the team. On the flip side of the coin it is important to arrange your testing sessions to be executed inside sprints so, it is the way you use tools that really matters.

Personally I do not see any specific drawbacks in using Excel for Test Scenario and Test Cases (of course you will lose the powerful of specific softwares), maybe you could separate Scenarios in Word files while using Excel sheets for tracking progressive test runs (one sheet for each new execution).